# Vb, sorting lists

Tags: vb.net, list, class, sorting

I have a question concerning sorting lists of classes in VB.Net. 
It seems every subject which is discussing this kind of sorting is not really clear for me.

I have a class Language with the following variables:
- Lang as a string
- Knowledge as a integer

I have got a list containing a couple of language classes in it. How can I sort on the Lang variable (Alphabetically sort the language classes in the list)?

Greetings,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your class, then use [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Private Class Language : Implements IComparable(Of Language)
  Public Property Lang As String
  Public Property Knowledge As Integer

  Sub New(lang As String)
    Me.Lang = lang
  End Sub

  Public Function CompareTo(other As Language) As Integer _
                                    Implements IComparable(Of Language).CompareTo
    Dim comp As Integer = Me.Lang.CompareTo(other.Lang)
    'If comp = 0 Then Return Me.Knowledge.CompareTo(other.Knowledge)
    Return comp
  End Function
End Class

Sub Main()
  Dim lst As New List(Of Language)
  lst.Add(New Language("fr"))
  lst.Add(New Language("en"))
  lst.Add(New Language("de"))
  lst.Sort()
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Added a hint on how to sort by multiple properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was all info I needed!

Comment: Is it also possible to sort/compare on two variables? 
 
Say I first sort on Lang first. if I have two Lang, than sort on the knowledge level?

Comment: @Sliver2009: You can put an if statement, i.e. If result of `CompareTo` equals to 0, make another `CompareTo`, and return that.

Comment: @Sliver2009: I modified my example, please check it out. Reference: [CompareTo @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I am not an expert in VB.Net, but I get the rationale behind comparing now!

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in a previous StackOverflow question: [Sort a List of Object in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735902/sort-a-list-of-object-in-vb-net)

Use Sort along with a custom function to compare the Lang variable.

```
theList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Lang.CompareTo(y.Lang))
```

Comment: I saw that topic to, but I do not get the following:

Function(x, y) x.Lang.CompareTo(y.Lang)

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework are you using?  Older versions do not support these functions; you need LINQ and lambda functionality to do it.

Comment: Sort accepts a function as an argument.
This function is how two elements are compared to decide how one element is put infront of another.
The function written in that code compares the 2 elements by their Lang variable, ordering them via it.

Comment: So something like:

Private Sub Counter(Language x, Language y)
       if x > y then ..?
End Sub

list.Sort(Counter xLang.CompareTo(y.Lang)

And I do not understand how a function should be? (It should return two values? Both x and y?)

Comment: Grim, even with .NET 2.0 you can specify a function as an argument for Sort, you just need it predefined.