# sort list of objects in VB.NET by two elements

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, object

I would like an extension of a question previously posted here

[Sort a List of Object in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735902/sort-a-list-of-object-in-vb-net)

In that question, the OP is asking how to sort a list of objects in VB.NET.

His example uses something like

```
passenger.name
passenger.age
passenger.surname
```

And then, the accepted answer uses

```
theList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.age.CompareTo(y.age))
```

To that point, everything is ok.

My extension to this is to ask what happens if, for example, I am sorting by age, like the example, however, let's say that 2 passengers have the same age, then, in that case, I would like to use a second parameter (let's say `passenger.name`), to sort.

Could it be done using the same `theList.Sort` expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom `IComparer(Of Passenger)` for `List.Sort`:

```
Class PassengerComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Passenger)
    Public Function Compare(p1 As Passenger, p2 As Passenger) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Passenger).Compare
        If p1.Age = p2.Age AndAlso p1.Name = p2.Name Then
            Return 0
        ElseIf p1.Age <> p2.Age Then
            Return p1.Age.CompareTo(p2.Age)
        ElseIf p1.Name <> p2.Name Then
            Return p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Now you can use this:

```
list.Sort(New PassengerComparer())
```

Another way is to use LINQ:

```
Dim ordered = From obj In theList
              OrderBy obj.Age Ascending, obj.Name Ascending
theList = ordered.ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks, is it any "non-LINQ" option?

Comment: Thanks Tim, of course this passenger and age thing is not my case, but of course I can work with that, lots of thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember corretly it should be done by:

```
theList = theList.OrderBy(Function(x, y) x.age.CompareTo(y.age)).ThenBy(Function(x) x.name) ' .toList()
```