# Best data structure to store key value pairs when the following operations are required

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I need to store a list of key value pairs. The key value pair will be used by multiple classes, so ideally its something like a list of a structure I define.

```
Public Structure Person
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Weight As Decimal
End Structure

'all use Person
    class census
    class importpeople
    class determinebestdiet
    etc
```

1. I need to sort by value
2. I need to remove a person (by Person.ID) or add a new key value pair (and re-sort after each add)
3. I need to sum the total of all values

Seems like often people use dictionaries and then hack around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List<Person>` to help your work

1. Using the List.Sort method:
   `theList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.age.CompareTo(y.age))`
   Using the OrderBy extension method:
   `theList = theList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.age).ToList()`
   Details can see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736001/1050927
2. Just remove from list and call `Sort` or `OrderBy`.
   Depends on what you want to do, you can use `OrderBy` with `Skip` and `Take` to get specific nth person after sort.
3. Just `Sum` it
   `PersonList.Sum(Function(per) per.Weight)`

And I believe `Dictionary` can do the same too, just you can't reuse the `Person` only.