# Sort a list based on an item inside the list that is another list

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

As the titel says, but it gets even more complicated. this is some example code

```
class person
prop name as string
prop age as int
prop properties as List(of ExtraProps)

class ExtraProps
prop key as string
prop value as string
```

so say that i want to sort a list of class person based on an object ExtraProps.value where the Key = "name"

do note that i am working in vs2005 and in version 2.0 of .NET

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735902/sort-a-list-of-object-in-vb-net . You can implement your own comparison logic which should meet your requirements for a custom comparison logic

Comment: @Capricorn i get that. but the sorting gets a little complicated for me since i need it based on a list within the list. and i'm still in vs2005 in this project because it is at my job and i cannot just change the project stuff because i want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would like to thank @TimSchmelter For this answer. this works perfectly in .NET 2.0 and in VS2005.

```
Public Class TaskKeyComparer
Implements IComparer(Of Trimble_Planning.TaskData)

Private ReadOnly _keyComparison As StringComparison
Private ReadOnly _valueComparison As StringComparison
Private ReadOnly _key As String

Public Sub New(ByVal key As String, Optional ByVal keyComparison As StringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture, Optional ByVal valueComparison As StringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    _key = key
    _keyComparison = keyComparison
    _valueComparison = valueComparison
End Sub

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As person, ByVal y As person) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of person).Compare
    If x Is Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return 0
    If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return CInt(IIf(x Is Nothing, -1, 1))
    If x.properties Is Nothing AndAlso y.properties Is Nothing Then Return 0
    If x.properties Is Nothing OrElse y.properties Is Nothing Then Return CInt(IIf(x.properties  Is Nothing, -1, 1))

    Dim xKeyValue As String = Nothing
    Dim yKeyValue As String = Nothing
    For Each prop As ExtraProps In x.properties 
        If String.Equals(prop.key, _key, _keyComparison) Then
            xKeyValue = prop.value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    For Each prop As ExtraProps In y.properties 
        If String.Equals(prop.key, _key, _keyComparison) Then
            yKeyValue = prop.value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return String.Compare(xKeyValue, yKeyValue, _valueComparison)
End Function
End Class
```

then use it like this

```
personList.Sort(New TaskKeyComparer("name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
Private Function ComparePersonsByExtraPropsName(p1 As Person, p2 As Person) As Integer
    Return GetFirstExtraProp(p1.Properties, "Name").Value.CompareTo(GetFirstExtraProp(p2.Properties, "Name").Value)
End Function

Private Function GetFirstExtraProp(properties As IEnumerable(Of ExtraProps), key As String) As ExtraProps
    For Each ep As ExtraProps In properties
        If ep.Key = key Then
            Return ep
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

and then:

```
Dim personList As New List(Of Person)

'...

personList.Sort(AddressOf ComparePersonsByExtraPropsName)
```

Comment: .NET 2 weas requested

Comment: when using this i get an error on the function part. it says Expression Expected.

Comment: Sorry, I did read the .NET 2.0 part and then promptly forgot about it.  I have edited the code to what should work in .NET 2.0.

Comment: @TimSchmelter your answer dissapeared?