# VB.NET Initial Sort Order

Tags: vb.net

To make a long story short, Mp3Tag for example, adds folders 1 to 5 first to last. When I add the same folders in my program it adds the folders from 5 (first) to 1 (last). Is there a way I can fix this?

Here's the code I've been using.

```
    If FolderBrowserDialogMain.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each mp3 In Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialogMain.SelectedPath, "*.mp3", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Dim fiFileInfo As New FileInfo(mp3)
            ListViewMain.Items.Add(fiFileInfo.Name)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Check out [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8). Just add an `.OrderBy(...)` on your `GetFiles(...)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a List of Object in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735902/sort-a-list-of-object-in-vb-net)

Comment: You probably want to order by the file name (not the full path). In that case, you could use something like `Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialogMain.SelectedPath)` and then `For Each fInfo As FileInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles(...).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)`.

Comment: Thanks Robil. I'll check out linq and see what happens.

Comment: Ahmed thanks for your input. I'll definitely look into all the answers. Thanks guys.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe add .Reverse to reverse the files?

```
If FolderBrowserDialogMain.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    For Each mp3 In Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialogMain.SelectedPath, "*.mp3", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Reverse()
        Dim fiFileInfo As New FileInfo(mp3)
        ListViewMain.Items.Add(fiFileInfo.Name)
    Next
End If
```